# Taking maven artifacts from Private Repository and Deploying to Server

Tags: java, maven

I have successfully set my projects to be released to a private repository.
There is a main project and a number of library projects.
Every atrifact has released and versioned properly using the release plugin.

e.g.
Program version 1.0.1 is dependant on Library A 2.3.4 and Library B 4.3.2.
etc.

Of course the repo will have mutiple versions of the program and Libraries A and B.

I now want to know the process for taking the right resources out of a repository and deploying them onto servers. First onto Test servers, then later onto Production. Of course I must ensure the versions tested in test match the versions in production.

Our production environments shouldn't have any source code on them - they should just use the built artifacts from the repository.

I am trying to find out where this process is documented.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to do this, none definitively correct. I build a fat jar with the Spring Boot plugin, but some people use shading, and some use an exec/run task on the server and pull the dependencies individually.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is opinion-based. I am trying to find out how to get artifacts from the Maven repo deployed on a server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assemble all the required artifacts into a single distribution and deploy it on the test server and then later on production.

You can go through the below link on how to use maven assemble plugin.

[Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-2.6/)

You can also use [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). The main advantage of the shade plugin over the assembly plugin is that you gain more fine grained control, like the ability to merge several manifest files.